# WPMU add custom colum

Tags: multisite, user-meta, columns

I managed to add the columns that I wanted in all the wpmu sites using:

```
add_action('manage_users_columns', 'header_column');
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'manage_column', 10, 3);
add_filter('manage_users_sortable_columns', 'set_sortable_column');
```

but i want to add the same functionality to the main network and didn't find any hook for that purpose.Any help where to find those hooks?Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this filter:

> wpmu_blogs_columns

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_blogs_columns/